# SharePoint XSLT Column Display Name

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-2013

I currently try to display the column name in a custom form in SharePoint Designer. I use Sharepoint 2013 so the design view doesnt exists anymore :(.
The form is used to create a new element in a custom list.
I cant put the name directly in the tempate because i would like use this template in different forms so i have to recover the name of my columns dynamically.
The problem is that I only found the internal name. 
I saw in the datafileds tag there are couples where the internal name is relied to the display name but I didnt find how recover the display name with that too.

Is it only possible ? Someone has an idea to help me?

I put some code if u want to look at my code.
This part looks for an attribute where the name contains "question" and calls the template  "title_line" when it finds one. The function name() gives me the internal name, that is the pb...

```
<xsl:template match="Row">

 <xsl:for-each select="@*">
    <xsl:choose>                
        <xsl:when test="contains(name(),'Question')">
            <xsl:call-template name="title_line" >
                <xsl:with-param name="title" select="name()"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="class" select="'class_title'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:otherwise>    

   </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

This part is to display the title:

```
<xsl:template name="title_line" >
        <xsl:param name="title" select="'no title'" />
        <xsl:param name="class" select="'no_class'" />
        <tr>
            <td colspan ="2" class="{$class}" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:medium">
                <xsl:value-of select="$title" />
            </td>
        </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

**MY SOLUTION :**

I used JQuery 1.9.0 and SPServices 0.7.2

Import these libraries into the header.
The ContentPlacdeHolderId *PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead* is at the bottom of the page, i didnt see it and have some problems because of the duplicate...)
About the source, i activated the publishing and create a folder Scripts into the Styles Library.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="FormCustomRedirectControl" AllowMultipleControls="true"/>
    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="forms.css" runat="server"/>

            <!-- add JQuery 1.9.0-->
            <script id ="JQUERY_ID" type="text/javascript" src="../../Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js">
            </script>   

            <!-- add SPServices 0.7.2 -->
            <script id ="JQUERY_ID" type="text/javascript" src="../../Style Library/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.js">
            </script>   

        </ContentTemplate>
    </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
```

Now the display of the title is :

```
<xsl:template name="title_line" >
    <xsl:param name="title" select="'no title'" />
    <xsl:param name="class" select="'no_class'" />
    <tr>
        <td colspan ="2" class="{$class}" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:medium">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var static_name = &apos;<xsl:value-of select="$title" />&apos;;
                var display_name = $().SPServices.SPGetDisplayFromStatic ({ 
                     listName: "listeperso",
                     columnStaticName: static_name
                });
                document.write(display_name);
            </script>
        </td>
    </tr>

</xsl:template>
```

I just need to have the name of the list dynamically and it's over.

Cya.

**EDIT** : the script with the list name dynamically

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var list_name = $().SPServices.SPListNameFromUrl();
    var static_name = &apos;<xsl:value-of select="$title" />&apos;;
    var display_name = $().SPServices.SPGetDisplayFromStatic ({ 
        listName : list_name,
        columnStaticName: static_name
    });
    document.write(display_name);
</script>
```

listName uses either the list name either the list ID. SPListNameFromUrl returns the list ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used JQuery 1.9.0 and SPServices 0.7.2

Import these libraries into the header.
The ContentPlacdeHolderId *PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead* is at the bottom of the page, i didnt see it and have some problems because of the duplicate...)
About the source, i activated the publishing and create a folder Scripts into the Styles Library.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="FormCustomRedirectControl" AllowMultipleControls="true"/>
    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="forms.css" runat="server"/>

            <!-- add JQuery 1.9.0-->
            <script id ="JQUERY_ID" type="text/javascript" src="../../Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js">
            </script>   

            <!-- add SPServices 0.7.2 -->
            <script id ="JQUERY_ID" type="text/javascript" src="../../Style Library/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.js">
            </script>   

        </ContentTemplate>
    </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
```

Now the display of the title is :

```
<xsl:template name="title_line" >
    <xsl:param name="title" select="'no title'" />
    <xsl:param name="class" select="'no_class'" />
    <tr>
        <td colspan ="2" class="{$class}" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:medium">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var static_name = &apos;<xsl:value-of select="$title" />&apos;;
                var display_name = $().SPServices.SPGetDisplayFromStatic ({ 
                     listName: "listeperso",
                     columnStaticName: static_name
                });
                document.write(display_name);
            </script>
        </td>
    </tr>

</xsl:template>
```

I just need to have the name of the list dynamically and it's over.

Cya.

**EDIT** : the script with the list name dynamically

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var list_name = $().SPServices.SPListNameFromUrl();
    var static_name = &apos;<xsl:value-of select="$title" />&apos;;
    var display_name = $().SPServices.SPGetDisplayFromStatic ({ 
        listName : list_name,
        columnStaticName: static_name
    });
    document.write(display_name);
</script>
```

listName uses either the list name either the list ID. SPListNameFromUrl returns the list ID.

Answer (score 0):

I see anybody have an idea.
I find a Javascript library SPServices which can convert the static name t the display name.

[Link](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPGetDisplayFromStatic&referringTitle=Documentation)

My new is to integrate the script. I tried to put it into the header like that :

> ```
> <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js">
>     </script>   
>     <script type="text/javascript" >
>        var azerty="jquery script";
>        alert($azerty);
>        $(document).ready(function() {
>            alert("jQuery");
>        });
>     </script>
> </asp:Content>
> ```

But the import doesnt appear into the generated page. Someone has an idea ?